# Is it possible to use a push notification with no local app

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, push-notification

I'd have a requirement, for a cloud service (C# .NET) to send a text message (eg a calendar reminder) to a subscribed user, on their mobile device (initially for iOS devices, then Android and WP7 later).

Is there a way of doing this without a local app on their device?

Found [this interesting article](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/37159628/Notifications) regarding notifications methods on mobile devices, and [Apples APN docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1), but it appears you need a local app.

However, with APN's, it appears that the OS displays the message for you even when the app is not running - so I thought it might be possible (although I did note to register for APN's you need a cert for your app).

Maybe there is some other technique?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Can't you send the calendar reminder entity to the user's email? I think most email client can make use of the calendar reminder entity to auto add to event. Heck even if you send a date in an email, apple's iOS system will detect a date event and convert it to a hyperlink when clicked will add the event to the user's calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is possible, it is probably Apple's internal functionality, as they wouldn't want anybody to be able to spam their customers.

Local app in this case acts as an API key. Apple knows who is sending push notifications to user's devices, because they are sent through your app signed with your certificate. So they can potentially punish you, if you abuse push notification functionality.

When you work with APN, first you need to obtain device's token, which is sent to your servers when user agrees to receive push notifications from your app. Then using that token you can send this user a push notification. Without local app you have no way of obtaining this token, so you won't be able to send any user a push message.

TL;DR It is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Probably not relevant to your use case scenario... it is possible to send an Apple Push Notification to an iOS device by installing a device settings management Enrollment configuration profile instead of an app.

This is how Apple's [Mobile Device Manager (MDM)](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/mdm/) system works.